# Can I use an NSFetchedResultsController without a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

What I want to do is select from my core data entity and effectively group by the date attribute.

So it will return something like this:

```
NSDictionary results {
    NSDate 01/01/2011 => NSArray { NSManagedObject obj1, NSManagedObject obj2, NSManagedObject obj3 }
    NSDate 02/01/2011 => NSArray { NSManagedObject obj4 }
    NSDate 03/01/2011 => NSArray { NSManagedObject obj5, NSManagedObject obj6 }
}
```

I hope that makes sense. I don't know if I'm even using the right class. I have heard/read that using the `sectionNameKeyPath:@"date"` helps with splitting a table view into sections. I don't want to do this, I just want to be able to access the sections in an array/dictionary structure.

Can you give me an example of how to use this? Its different from the usual:

```
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:...]
```

I'm used to...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a NSFetchedResultsController without a UITableView.

Take a look at the sectionIndexTitles property. That returns an array of sections based on your sectionNameKeyPath. In your case, it should return an array of NSDates.

You could then use the objectAtIndexPath method to access the records in each group and build an array of records to load into your dictionary.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think the resolution of NSDate (nanosecond) will make this rather difficult to use. You might consider adding a transient property to your entity which computes the date in the correct format for NSFetchedResultsController to group the values correctly.

Comment: oh thanks, but its ok. When setting the date I'm just taking the day month and year components and storing the time as a separate attribute, for this exact reason.